# jQuery smooth scroll to specific part of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I smooth scroll down to a specific part of the page?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="scrollToBottom"><img src="images/godown.png" alt="Down Arrow" width="116" /></a>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){

 // Scroll page to the bottom
 $('a.scrollToBottom').click(function(){

 $('html, body, .content').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 1500);

 return false;

 });
})
</script>
```

Now what that code does is that when I click on the "godown.png" image, it will work but it will go to the end of the bottom of the page. Anyway to make it go to the middle? And how would I define the middle with #middle or something?

Comment: "Anyway to make it go to the middle?" $(document).height()/2

Answer (score 2):

To make it smooth add **e.preventDefault();** in the scrolling function

```
$('a.scrollToBottom').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('html, body, .content').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 1500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to a specific part of the page you can use the jQuery function offset [ http://api.jquery.com/offset/ ] to calculate the offset of the element relative to the page. Then you can scrolltop to a certain position in the document.

Example

html:

```
<a href="#">scroll to c</a>
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">b</div>
<div id="c">c</div>
```

js with jQuery:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    var targetOffset= $("#c").offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1500);
    e.preventDefault();    
});
```

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/rniestroj/FkCK8/

Answer (score 0):

try this :)

```
$("a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var targetOffset = $(".content").offset().top + 1500;
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 0);
});
```